# Swift line break not working after loading from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, line-breaks, userdefaults

I'm loading a string from UserDefaults and set the text of a TextView to that string. When it includes a line break character, it will just display the line break character in the TextView and not an actual line break.

I save a short bio in UserDefaults and want to be able to include a line break (example: "My Name\n25 Years Old"). I'm setting this bio through a textField which is why I want to use the line break character. When I'm displaying that value inside a textView, it shows the line break character and doesn't do an actual line break.

Two examples with code:

```
textView.text = "My Name\n25 Years Old"
```

When setting the text like this, the line break character works properly and the textView displays:
*My Name
25 Years Old*

```
let text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "text")
textView.text = text
```

When setting the text like this, the line break character does NOT work and the textView displays:
*My Name\n25Years Old*

Does anyone know why this is happening and a possible fix?

Comment: I wouldn't store the line break character in UserDefaults, just store the original string and do whatever work you need to do with it after fetching.

Comment: I expect you have a mistake in how you're storing the string in user defaults. The following does not reproduce your problem (with a UITextView added to the storyboard). https://gist.github.com/rnapier/048aebdb39186392c81ca84fdd8649c7 Please include a MCRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Show all relevant code for how you store the text in UserDefaults and where that text originally comes from.

Comment: I'm storing the text in UserDefaults like so: let bio = bioField.text       UserDefaults.standard.set(bio, forKey: "bio")      where bioField is just a textField.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution that works with UserDefaults. We can ask the user to use something like "/n/" to indicate a line break when entering the text in the textField and then we can save the string to UserDefaults. Then, when loading the string from UserDefaults to display in a textView, we can separate it by that "/n/" character and set the textView text to the substring with the actual line break character in between.

For example:

Save the text (Use /n/ for a line break):

```
let text = textField.text
UserDefaults.standard.set(text, forKey: "text")
```

The text saved in UserDefaults might look something like "My First Text /n/ My Second Text /n/ My Third Text"

Load the text:

```
let text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "text")
let textArray = text.components(separatedBy: "/n/")
var string = ""
for i in textArray {
            string.append("\(i)\n")
        }
textView.text = string
```

This will work no matter how many line breaks the user enters.